# What are the conditions required by a US bank to withdraw an international wire transfer?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, withdrawal, wire-transfer

A friend of mine was probably close to being defrauded (he is a painter, someone sent him a document certifying that he did a wire transfer to his bank for three painting he wants to buy, asked for some shady "transport arrangements" right away yada yada yada).

I told him that this is very likely to be a scam and so that he does not do anything before seeing the money on his account. We are French, the "customer" is "American"

**My question the following**: under which conditions would a US bank accept a request from a customer of theirs to withdraw a wire transfer said customer did to a foreign bank?

In other words: how easy would it be for the "customer" of my friend to get his money back, once they manded on my friend's account?

Comment: Ask the bank. But as far as I've been told, wire transfers are Not. Reversible.

Comment: by the way it is not *necessarily* fraud, it is just veeeeery suspicious.

Comment: @user253751: in the EU they are (under tight conditions). I know that this may not be fraud, we will see when the money actually flows in.

Comment: A legitimate payer (accountholder) would not normally be able to reverse a wire. But the fraudster doesn't transfer their own money, they transfer money stolen from someone else. And the _courts_ can take back stolen money -- although it goes back to the victim, not the fraudster who never legitimately had it to start with.

Answer (score -1):

Wire Transfers are NOT reversible. So it would be pretty hard to get the money back once it is Wire Transfered unless your friend sends the money by mail.

Comment: You mean that in the US there is no way to reverse them? Say, if your company sends twice your salary by mistake, this cannot be reversed when this is an obvious mistake? (this is certainly the case in the EU). If there is provision for such cases, are they documented?

Comment: What i am saying is once they wire it to you, they cant pull the wire back, you will have to wire them back half of the money to make your salary equal.

Comment: Ok lets say it this way, Your company wires you 20k which is an obvious mistake because your salary is 10k. They cant reverse that wire transfer, you will have to wire 10k back to them.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where this is documented because I find it really weird that wire transactions in the US would be so vastly different from the ones I know from elsewhere (just a few data points in the EU and one in Asia, but still).

Comment: https://laws101.com/can-you-reverse-a-wire-transfer/

Comment: Its only possible if the bank accepts the wire cancellation